# Returning parent key based on a value in a list of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
{
"arr1":[
    {
      "name":"something1",
      "id":"233111f4-9126-490d-a78b-1724009fa484"
    },
    {
       "name":"something2",
       "id":"50584c03-ac71-4225-9c6a-d12bcc542951"
    },
    {
       "name":"Unique",
       "id":"43cf14ee58ea4d8da43e9a2f208d215c"
    },
    {
       "name":"something4",
       "id":"ce0374ba-6d9b-4ff5-98b1-1191d1d2a9a7"
    },
    {
       "name":"something5",
       "id":"ef825dc3-003c-4740-955a-bb437cfb4199"
    }
],

"arr2":
 [
   {
     "name":"Unique",
     "id":"43cf14ee58ea4d8da43e9a2f208d215c"}
 ]
}
```

This is list of arrays with keys and values as array, I want to return all the keys based on a particular value;

For Eg:
I want to return the parent keys which are **[arr1,arr2]**, reason being both the arrays contain a value **Unique**, So I want to return the parent key of both the values, which is arr1 and arr2 respectively.

**Note**: The list can have n numbers of arrays.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, provide the code with what you have tried so far and what you have struggles with right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to go about this is:

- Loop through the keys in your object
- Check if the array contains any objects with the name "Unique"
- If so, add the objects key to an array

```js
const obj = {
  "arr1": [{ "name": "something1", "id": "233111f4-9126-490d-a78b-1724009fa484" }, { "name": "something2", "id": "50584c03-ac71-4225-9c6a-d12bcc542951" }, { "name": "Unique", "id": "43cf14ee58ea4d8da43e9a2f208d215c" }, { "name": "something4", "id": "ce0374ba-6d9b-4ff5-98b1-1191d1d2a9a7" }, { "name": "something5", "id": "ef825dc3-003c-4740-955a-bb437cfb4199" }],
  "arr2": [{ "name": "Unique", "id": "43cf14ee58ea4d8da43e9a2f208d215c" }],
  "arr3": [{ "name": "No unique here","id": "Example" }]
}

// Create our array that will contain the keys
const keys = []
// Loop through each key in the object
for (const prop in obj) {
  // Use .some to see if any of the objects in this array have the selected name
  const containsUnique = obj[prop].some(o => o.name === 'Unique')
  if (containsUnique) {
    // Add the current key to the array
    keys.push(prop)
  }
}
// Use the array of keys which contain an object named "Unique"
console.log(keys)
```

Comment: You can use the filter loop https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @SullivanTobias You could, but it doesn't really matter how many objects have that name within the array, so just `find()`ing the first items should be slightly more efficient I think (as it only finds the first match)

Comment: `.some()` is even more better than checking truthy/falsy, since it just returns true/false.

Comment: @DBS Thanks that's a great solution, One last question I have, What if this operation is being triggered on an event which gives me the unique value, In that case it will keep on pushing the prop and as an end result I will be getting repeated values inside the key array.

Comment: @Vish If you want to compare against another value, you can just replace `'Unique'` with a variable containing your string. I'm not sure I understand the repeated values question, this should only be able to return/not return each key in the object, and since objects keys have to be unique, there should never be a repeated string in the `keys` array. (Edit: If you run it multiple times, be sure to create a new empty `keys` array each time)

Answer (score 2):

This is a more generic approach:

```js
const getKeysByValue = (data, value) => {
    const dataKeys = Object.keys(data);
    const valueKey = Object.keys(value);
    return dataKeys.filter(currKey => {
        for(let element of data[currKey])
            if(element[valueKey] === value[valueKey]) 
                return true;
    });
}

const data = {
    "arr1":[
        {
          "name":"something1",
          "shape": "Trapezium",
          "id":"233111f4-9126-490d-a78b-1724009fa484"
        },
        {
           "name":"something2",
           "shape": "Octagon",
           "id":"50584c03-ac71-4225-9c6a-d12bcc542951"
        },
        {
           "name":"Unique",
           "shape": "Square",
           "id":"43cf14ee58ea4d8da43e9a2f208d215c"
        },
        {
           "name":"something4",
           "shape": "Triangle",
           "id":"ce0374ba-6d9b-4ff5-98b1-1191d1d2a9a7"
        },
        {
           "name":"something5",
           "shape": "Circle",
           "id":"ef825dc3-003c-4740-955a-bb437cfb4199"
        }
    ],
    
    "arr2":
     [
        {
         "name":"Unique",
         "shape": "Triangle",
         "id":"43cf14ee58ea4d8da43e9a2f208d215c"
        }
     ],

     "arr3":
     [
        {
         "name":"Not-Unique",
         "shape": "Circle",
         "id":"8hcf14ee58ea25g343e9a2f208df215c"
        }
     ]
}

console.log(getKeysByValue(data, {"name": "something2"})); // ["arr1"]
console.log(getKeysByValue(data, {"name": "Unique"})); // ["arr1", "arr2"]
console.log(getKeysByValue(data, {"shape": "Circle"})); // ["arr1", "arr3"]
console.log(getKeysByValue(data, {"shape": "Square"})); // ["arr1"]
```

The function receives two parameters, `data` and `value`. `value` is expected to be in the format of the value you are looking to filter with. In your example you wanted it to be `"Unique"` and in each object in the array it was presented like `"name": "Unique"` so we will send it as an object, `{"name": "Unique"}`.

In this way you can have different value to filter with. In the example above I added a shape key and value to each element, we can filter by this value too as shown in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this  :

```
const obj = {
  "arr1": [{ "name": "something1", "id": "233111f4-9126-490d-a78b-1724009fa484" }, { "name": "something2", "id": "50584c03-ac71-4225-9c6a-d12bcc542951" }, { "name": "Unique", "id": "43cf14ee58ea4d8da43e9a2f208d215c" }, { "name": "something4", "id": "ce0374ba-6d9b-4ff5-98b1-1191d1d2a9a7" }, { "name": "something5", "id": "ef825dc3-003c-4740-955a-bb437cfb4199" }],
  "arr2": [{ "name": "Unique", "id": "43cf14ee58ea4d8da43e9a2f208d215c" }],
  "arr3": [{ "name": "No unique here","id": "Example" }]
}

arr=[]
//loop over dict with pair keys and value 
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
//get the list of name from dict and check it if it contains Unique string 
  value.map(e=>e.name).includes("Unique") ? arr.push(key) : false
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array `some` method

```js
const data = {
  "arr1": [{
      "name": "something1",
      "id": "233111f4-9126-490d-a78b-1724009fa484"
    },
    {
      "name": "something2",
      "id": "50584c03-ac71-4225-9c6a-d12bcc542951"
    },
    {
      "name": "Unique",
      "id": "43cf14ee58ea4d8da43e9a2f208d215c"
    },
    {
      "name": "something4",
      "id": "ce0374ba-6d9b-4ff5-98b1-1191d1d2a9a7"
    },
    {
      "name": "something5",
      "id": "ef825dc3-003c-4740-955a-bb437cfb4199"
    }
  ],

  "arr2": [{
    "name": "Unique",
    "id": "43cf14ee58ea4d8da43e9a2f208d215c"
  }]
}

var obj = [],
  keys;
for (keys in data) {
  data[keys].some(a => "Unique" === a.name) && obj.push(keys);
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way that i could think of is using Regexp

```
var obj = {
"arr1":[
    {
      "name":"something1",
      "id":"233111f4-9126-490d-a78b-1724009fa484"
    },
    {
       "name":"something2",
       "id":"50584c03-ac71-4225-9c6a-d12bcc542951"
    },
    {
       "name":"Unique",
       "id":"43cf14ee58ea4d8da43e9a2f208d215c"
    },
    {
       "name":"something4",
       "id":"ce0374ba-6d9b-4ff5-98b1-1191d1d2a9a7"
    },
    {
       "name":"something5",
       "id":"ef825dc3-003c-4740-955a-bb437cfb4199"
    }
],

"arr2":
 [
   {
     "name":"Unique",
     "id":"43cf14ee58ea4d8da43e9a2f208d215c"}
 ]
}

let str = JSON.stringify(obj);
let match = str.matchAll(/\"([\w\d]+)\":\[(?:{[\s\S]+},)*{\"name\":\"Unique\"/g);

let parent = [];
for(let m of match){
   parent.push(m[1]);
}
```